# MySQL - Find all rows with at least 3 matching columns

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table like following:

```
Id  | bool1 | bool2 | bool3 | bool4 | boo5 | bool6
100 | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1     | 1    | 0
300 | 0     | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1    | 1
600 | 0     | 0     | 1     | 0     | 1    | 1
```

I would like to have to get all rows that have at least 3 matching (true) booleans with a given row:

```
500 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0| 1
```

So, Id 100 and Id 300 should be return, but not Id 600.
I tried a few things like CROSS JOIN and all type of other joins and subqueries. However, I couldnt quite figure out how to solve this query.

My issue here is not 6 booleans, its 25 that have to be compared.

Any help is much appreciated.

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18480e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a join of the table to the *given* row on the condition that you set:

```
select p.*
from product p inner join(select * from product where id = 500) c
on (c.bool1 = p.bool1) + (c.bool2 = p.bool2) + (c.bool3 = p.bool3) + 
   (c.bool4 = p.bool4) + (c.bool5 = p.bool5) + (c.bool6 = p.bool6) >= 3
where p.id <> c.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/t4QSdRW28hxV1Ac1NhfYnv/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | bool1 | bool2 | bool3 | bool4 | bool5 | bool6 |
| --- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- |
| 100 | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1     | 1     | 0     |
| 300 | 0     | 1     | 0     | 1     | 1     | 1     |
```

Comment: Thanks, this actually could work however would still make me have to type in 25 columns (maybe even more later on). If you have an idea to have it more dynamically without having to add each individual column i would be extremely happy. For the moment i could settle on your solution Thanks a bunch

Comment: Maybe a different design would work better for this purpose. If the number of columns may change why don't you create a table with id, nr, booleanvalue. The column nr will be the index of the boolean value.

Comment: Then you could get the results that you want by aggregation. The number of rows of the table would be x25 but it would be easier to query.

Comment: given that im expecting to put a lot of data in it i thought this solution might actually be a bit better regarding performance than having joins to compare an additional table. Do you have any idea of what is faster (lets say with 500k entries matched against 1?)

Comment: In that case, for 500k rows I can't tell and I wouldn't suggest to multiply them by 25. You will have to test.

Comment: You can try this design, which would work for any number of boolean columns: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sM74Mf9c4WA2NCUvTJGivu/0 but you will have to test its efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     t t500
where t500.id = 500 and
      ( (t.bool1 and t500.bool1) +
        (t.bool2 and t500.bool2) +
        (t.bool3 and t500.bool4) +
        (t.bool4 and t500.bool5) +
        (t.bool5 and t500.bool6)
      ) >= 3
```

This assumes that the matching row is in your table.  If not:

```
select t.*
from t cross join
     (select 500 as id, 1 as bool1, 1 as bool2, 1 as bool3, 1 as bool4, 0 as bool5, 1 as bool6
     ) t500
where ( (t.bool1 and t500.bool1) +
        (t.bool2 and t500.bool2) +
        (t.bool3 and t500.bool4) +
        (t.bool4 and t500.bool5) +
        (t.bool5 and t500.bool6)
      ) >= 3
```